# Getting 404 error when try to resttemplate getforobject

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have catalog service that works with product service to get data (microservices). When I try to make getForObject in catalog service, I have an error 404.

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/catalog")
    public class ProductCatalogApi {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String hello(){
        return "Heelloooo";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{category}")
    public void getProductsByCategoryName(@PathVariable String category) {
        UserProduct  userProduct = restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://shop-product-service/shop/products" + category,
                UserProduct.class);
        System.out.println("dsdasa--------"+ userProduct);
    }
```

This is my product service:

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/shop")
    public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Product> index(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id_product}")
    public Optional<Product> showByProductId(@PathVariable String id_product){
        return productRepository.findById(id_product);
    }

    @GetMapping("/products/{category}")
    public List<Product> showByCategoryName(@PathVariable String category){
        return productRepository.findByCategory(category);
    }

    }
```

So when I try to make link this: http://localhost:8082/catalog/electronics, I get error, Please help me.

Comment: Are you using docker? Where are you making your above mentioned request from (browser/ product service)?

Comment: it seems you are missing / for this line http://shop-product-service/shop/products" + category,

Answer (score 2):

you lost the character "/" in the class ProductCatalogApi :

restTemplate.getForObject("http://shop-product-service/shop/products" + category,
                UserProduct.class);

http://shop-product-service/shop/products =>
http://shop-product-service/shop/products/